# MYSQL tee syntax not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Can anyone help me with this? I am currently trying to write my queries to a file and I will eventually close it with notee; call. I have used the tee call before but for some reason today I am having problems.

Here is the syntax in question:

```
tee c:/trash/test.txt;
select*from customer;
```

Here is the Error:

```
Error
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 6
STR: :/
SQL: tee c:/trash/test.txt;tee c:/trash/test.txt;tee c:/trash/test.txt;

SQL query:

tee c:/trash/test.txt;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tee c:/trash/test.txt' at line 1
```

The file trash has been created so I know that is not the issue.

Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `tee` and `notee` commands are only available in [the MySQL command-line client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html). They are not handled by the server, so they cannot be used in applications like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Sounds good that is where I have used tee before in the command line. Never in Php admin do I use OUTFILE in this case?

Comment: Does Outfile allow multiple writes to the same file?